# How to start countdown for 8 hour in formula field after calculated Now ()-CreatedDate

Tags: formula, formula-field

I am getting result after one minute  in formula field like this   0 Days 0 Hours -479 Minutes.
I need result like this    0 Days 7 Hours -59 Minutes.

This is my formula but it's not working properly

```
TEXT( FLOOR(Now() - CreatedDate))  & " Days " &TEXT(
ROUND(MOD((Now() - CreatedDate)*24,24),0) )  &" Hours " &
TEXT(ROUND(MOD((Now() - CreatedDate)*1440,60),0)-480
) &" Minutes "
```

Please if you have any solution thanks in advance.

Comment: To ensure no-one is wasting their time providing a solution - What are you using the countdown for? Are you aware that the formula will not trigger anything? If the record is not accessed then the formula will do nothing until the record is viewed again. Just want to make sure that the ultimate goal you are going for can be met. If it is just display only then no worries

Comment: Thank santanu for reply

i want to subtract 8 hour from this {Now ()-CreatedDate}
it can be happen because i not aware of these thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will work, put other boundary condition if that apply.

```
IF(FLOOR( (NOW()- CreatedDate)) > 0,TEXT( FLOOR( (NOW()- CreatedDate)) ) & " days ", "") 
& TEXT(7 - FLOOR( MOD( (NOW()- CreatedDate)* 24, 24 ) ) ) & " hours " 
& TEXT( 59 - ROUND( MOD( (NOW()- CreatedDate)* 24 * 60, 60 ), 0 ) ) & " minutes "
```

> Created Date is : 7/2/2017 10:38 AM
>
> Current Time is : 7/2/2017 2:53 PM
>
> So, elapsed time is from Created Date: 4 hours and 15 minutes
>
> **Formula output:** 3 hours 45 minutes

(All times are EST)

Comment: Hi Santanu
I need to calculate in negative when time hits 0. So, if priority is p1, I need to start from 0 hour 30 min. As per your above solution, If do it for p1, it start adding 1 hour when minutes is -30. But it should add 1 hour only when minutes is -59 or-60th min. Here is my formula,
`IF( ISPICKVAL(Priority_Time__c, "P1"),
IF(FLOOR( (NOW()- CreatedDate)) > 0,TEXT( FLOOR( (NOW()- CreatedDate)) ) & " days ", "") 
& TEXT(FLOOR( MOD( (NOW()- CreatedDate)* 24, 24 ) ) ) & " hours " 
& TEXT( 30 - ROUND( MOD( (NOW()- CreatedDate)* 24 * 60, 60 ), 0 ) ) & " minutes ",
"not found")`